# Поиск по SQL базе данных

Tags: sql, search

Не могу разобраться с кодом при поиске в базе данных, создал таблице забил значениями и попытался получить переменную в textbox но код почему то упорно не видит значение Name в строке и не выводит не чего в textbox. Только по поиск по id получилось вывести имя но в id цифры и поиск неудобен

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Veils\Desktop\Veilsapp\Veilsapp\Minerals.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Miner] WHERE Name LIKE 'Diamond'", con);
        SqlDataReader val = com.ExecuteReader();
        if(val.Read())
        {
            tb1.Text = (val["Name"].ToString());
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
    }
```

Вот SQL таблица
[image]

Comment: А в самом sql данный запрос правильно выполняется?

Comment: только в visual studio базу создал и после к wpf подключил а поиск организовать не могу

Comment: попробуйте выполнить запрос с '%Diamond%', может есть продолжение у строки в колонке Name

Comment: Заработало спасибо!)